# Errors with Port Forwarding and File Sync in NitrousIO Mac client

Tags: nitrousio

I am trying to get the MAC client app to sync files and enable port forwarding.

When I turn on port forwarding I get "Port Forwarding Error: Authentication failed."

When I turn on File Sync I get "File Sync Error: Lost connection with the server"

I can see my boxes in the client app and tell when they are running or not.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with NitrousIO tech support and it was an issue with ssh keys. They had to delete my keys on their end and register them again.

If this happens to you, you will want to contact support.

Comment: Deleting the key at https://www.nitrous.io/app#/public_keys and then readding it worked for me.